# После поворота экрана данные стираются в observableCache

Tags: java, android

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Disposable disposable;
    private Observable<ModelSearchItems> observableCache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            observableCache=RequestApi.getSearchItems()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).cache();
        }

        disposable=observableCache.subscribe(modelSearchItems -> {
            Log.e("MainActivity=onCreate", modelSearchItems.message.size() + "");
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так? В интернете прочитал статью про такой подход там чувак хвалил себя и у него все работало...

Получаю ошибку

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)' on a null object reference
                                                                                MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что здесь `if (savedInstanceState == null)` что-то не работает и `observableCache` все еще `null`. И почему бы вам его просто не сохранять в `savedInstanceState`?

Comment: @kulikovman, пожалуйста можно пример кода?

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения и восстановления данных во время поворота экрана используются методы `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState`. Чтобы сохранить ваш список объектов внутри `onSaveInstanceState` нужно использовать **Serializable** (проще) или **Parcelable** (производительней).

В итоге, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("key", (Serializable) mObservableCache);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    mObservableCache = (Observable<ModelSearchItems>) savedInstanceState.get("key");
}
```

Так же, возможно поможет прочтение [этой](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) статьи.

Comment: ошибку выдает `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.eranewgames.jeenchtest, PID: 31878
                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
                                                                                at MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:40)`